# Javascript a TD click and get row cell data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this in Jquery all works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#checktable td:nth-child(1)").click(function(event){ //  This line I need converted
        event.preventDefault();

        var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td'); //This line I need converted
        var tid = $td.eq(0).text();
        var tdate = $td.eq(1).text();
        var tdescribe = $td.eq(2).text();
        var wd = $td.eq(3).text();
        var dep = $td.eq(4).text();

        // ... more code
```

I need a similar thing in javascript, above only first td is clicked.

My javascript code so far:

```js
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("checktable2");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var tid = '';
    var tdate = '';
    var tdescribe = '';
    var wd = '';
    var dep = '';
    var tisclr = '';

    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].i = i;
        rows[i].onclick = function() {
            tid = table.rows[this.i].cells[0].innerText;
            tdate = table.rows[this.i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            tdescribe = table.rows[this.i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            wd = table.rows[this.i].cells[3].innerHTML;
            dep = table.rows[this.i].cells[4].innerHTML;

            // ... etc more code
```

The javascript works but any td can be clicked, I am after only:

- The first td clicked
- Then get parent row
- Then all child td's

I have been over dozens of StackOverflow posts and other sites as well...  Thanks

And how do I add the `event.preventDefault()` to regular JS in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

You'd bind the handler to the first `.cell`.

```
rows[i].cells[0].onclick = function () {
```

And then in the handler, access the `.parentNode` of `this` to get the row.

---

And since you're not closing over any variables except those in the function itself (and outside that function, of course), I'd just use a single handler instead of recreating it in the loop.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("checktable2");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var tid = '';
    var tdate = '';
    var tdescribe = '';
    var wd = '';
    var dep = '';
    var tisclr = '';

    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].i = i;
        rows[i].cells[0].onclick = handler;
    }
    function handler() {
            var row = this.parentNode;

            tid = this.innerText;
            tdate = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            tdescribe = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
            wd = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
            dep = row.cells[4].innerHTML;

           // etc more code
    }
}
```

I'd probably use a loop to get the desired content too. Maybe like this:

```
function handler() {
    var row = this.parentNode;
    var props = ["tid", "tdate", "tdescribe", "wd", "dep"];
    var content = props.reduce(function(obj, key, i) {
       obj[key] = row.cells[i][i ? "innerHTML" : "innerText"];
       return obj;
    }, {});

           // etc more code
}
```

Now instead of variables, you have properties of the `content` object.

Comment: Tat td is echo "<td onclick='addRowHandlers()'><a href=\"#\">" . $row['checkid'] . "</a></td>";

Comment: I know I'm doing something wrong, but in jquery the td doesn't need an onclick.  echo "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $row['checkid'] . "</a></td>";  because of this line  $("#checktable td:nth-child(1)").click(function (event)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. You don't need the handler in the HTML. It's in the `addRowHandlers` function here: `rows[i].cells[0].onclick = handler;`

Comment: The `rows[i].cells[0].onclick = handler` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Are you saying the handler doesn't fire?

Comment: Are you running the script after the DOM is loaded? In the jQuery code, you're using `$(document).ready(...)`. In Vanilla, I'd probably just put the script down toward the end of the document.

Comment: Yah, working I did not put the var row = this.parentNode; at first, thanks @slappy

Comment: One thing I just noticed, on first click of the td I get no response.  However the following clicks, all is working.  Is there a way to get it working on first click?  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Would need to see more code, but I'm guessing you're running `addRowHandlers` in a click event somewhere instead of having it run immediately after the page loads.

Comment: yes the row td is `echo "<td onclick='addRowHandlers()'><a href=\"#\">" . $row['checkid'] . "</a></td>";`  I am used of jquery, how would I do it after page load?  And would doing so affect other javascript functions on the page?

Comment: Okay, I just put `addRowHandlers();` right before `function addRowHandlers() {`  And removed `onclick='addRowHandlers()` from the td element, WOW it works.  Got idea from another S.O. post.

Comment: All your JS does need to cooperate, so the order in which things run can be important. But the main thing is that any initializing code that relies on the DOM elements being present must not run until those elements are in fact present. There are several approaches, but putting the script at the bottom of the page is simplest.